# How to fix WinSCP hanging at the very end of a transfer

Tags: winscp

I am trying to upload some larger in size binary type files (order 10^8 bytes) using WinSCP and somewhere around 96->100% I see it timing out.  Now in some cases, it seems that the entire file is being successfully transmitted and is usable even though it hangs.  I try to do reconnect and resume and start over, but none of these will lead to a transfer of the whole file without this timeout.

I see at the same time smaller text files I am transferring have no problem.

What might be causing this hang at the end and how might it be resolved?

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment (I deleted it), I did the math and realized you are talking about a 100 MB file, that is large but shouldn't be big enough to cause the issues I referring to, unless the end system is very slow.

Comment: What protocol? Log file?

Comment: I don't know if I can paste the whole log file but let me give you what I have for now and any other important info you need.  SFTP is the protocol.  I am using WinSCP 4.3.9.  I do see a strange line around the time of hang in the log file that reads `9803 Skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE SSH_FXP_READ SSH_FXP_DATA SSH_FXP_STATUS packets`  That number varies slightly per transfer attempt.